# str type error even though I am using int

Tags: python, list

Please help me out. If user enters 937, program should return 973, the biggest possible number.

This is my code:

```
list = []
cont = 1
while cont < 4:
    List.append(input(("Type digit ") + str(cont ) + (" of the number: ")))
    cont = cont + 1

print(list)
mayor = int(0)
menor = int(9)
cont = int(0)
while cont < 3:i
    if list[cont] > int(mayor):
        mayor = list[cont]
    if list[cont] < menor:
        menor = list[cont]

    cont = cont + 1

cont  = 0
while cont < 3:
    if list[cont] < mayor:
    if list[cont] > menor:
        m = list[cont]
cont = cont  + 1

list1 = []
list1.append(mayor)
list1.append(m)
list1.append(menor)

print(list1)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    if list[cont] > int(mayor):    
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Chances are whatever is in `list[cont]` is actually an `str`. So you probably have to do `int(list[cont])` as well to properly compare them with the same types.

Comment: Please post the actual code. The one in your question is full of typos, syntax errors and indentation issues.

Comment: What you are doing is only sorting the digits from biggest to smallest. You can do that in a single line : `result = ''.join(sorted(input_list,reverse=True))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue.

```
list = []
cont = 1
while cont < 4:
    list.append(input(("Ingrese el numero ") + str(cont ) + (" de la cifra: ")))
    cont = cont + 1

print("El numero ingresado es: " , list)
mayor = int(0)
menor = int(9)
cont = int(0)
while cont < 3:
    if int(list[cont]) > int(mayor):
        mayor = list[cont]
    if int(list[cont]) < int(menor):
        menor = list[cont]

    cont = cont + 1

cont  = 0
while cont < 3:
    if list[cont] < mayor:
        if list[cont] > menor:
            m = list[cont]

    cont = cont  + 1

list1 = []
list1.append(mayor)
list1.append(m)
list1.append(menor)

print("El mayor numero possible es: ",list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following method

```
list.sort()
m = list[1]
```

instead of this:

```
cont  = 0
while cont < 3:
    # if list[cont] < mayor:
    if list[cont] > menor:
        m = list[cont]
    cont = cont  + 1
```

Then try :

```
list = []
cont = 1
while cont < 4:
    list.append(input(("Type digit ") + str(cont ) + (" of the number: ")))
    cont = cont + 1

print(list)

mayor = 0
menor = 9
cont = 0

while cont < 3:
    if int(list[cont]) > int(mayor):
        mayor = list[cont]
    if int(list[cont]) < int(menor):
        menor = list[cont]

    cont = cont + 1

list.sort()
m = list[1] # second largest

list1 = []
list1.append(mayor)
list1.append(m)
list1.append(menor)

print("".join(list1))
```

**Input :**

```
Type digit 1 of the number: 2
Type digit 2 of the number: 5
Type digit 3 of the number: 7
```

**Output :**

```
['2', '5', '7']
752
```

Comment: I tried:
    Type digit 1 of the number: 2
    Type digit 2 of the number: 5
    Type digit 3 of the number: 7
    ['2', '5', '7']
    772

Comment: Fixed. @AshleyUreña